# How can I create an installer for individual files?

Tags: macos, install, package-management, pkg

I would like to create an installer (.app, .pkg?) for a selection of data files.

I need to place them in `~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CameraRaw`

I've been playing around with [WhiteBox Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) and I'm able to successfully create a .pkg that will install a file to the desktop, but for some reason it will not place the same file in the Library directory I specified above. The installer runs without error, but it does not copy the payload into the CameraRaw directory.

What am I doing wrong? Why does it successfully copy a file to the desktop but not to the CameraRaw directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, this was it:

The installer was working as it should, but it was placing my files into

```
Macintosh HD/Library/Application Support/...
```

instead of

```
Macintosh HD/users/<username>/Library/Application Support/...
```

now I just need to modify the destination to point to the correct folder.